# Avoiding IllegalStateException “Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

This topic has so many different SO questions linked to it, I know, but I think most people ask their questions while still confused about why things happen when.

I've read [Alex Lockwood](https://plus.google.com/+AlexLockwood?prsrc=5)'s article on [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html), and although he provides clear arguments for all things (read the article - it's really informative and easy to understand), he doesn't provide a full proof work around for my situation - using `AsyncTask`s.

Here's what we do in our app:

1. User presses a button which initiates an `AsycTask` doing a call to our server.
2. A phone call is initiated from within the app using `Intent.ACTION_CALL`.
3. Phone call is ended and user returns to the app.
4. `AsyncTask` responds with server call response.
5. App code processes the response and displays output to user.

So obviously, when the user goes to the phone call, our app is stopped. So when the `AsyncTask` gets to `onPostExecute()` and provides the server call response, we might not be in a live activity, and it's probably after `onSaveInstanceState()` has been called.

So how do I solve this?

I have to communicate the results of the server call response to the user through an `AlertDialogFragment`, but when I want to show that alert, I get IllegalStateException.

Alex Lockwood suggests that I make sure that no fragment transactions occur after `onSaveInstanceSate()` has been called - i.e. (I figure) don't trigger anything in the app (like displaying an alert), from the `onPostExecute()` of an `AsycTask`.

So when then?

Should I do something in `onResume()` like check there whether I've received a response from that `AsyncTask` server call, which I should probably save to shared prefs rather than process and present results to the user, and if so, display that alert to the user?

Please advise?

Comment: Have you tried using an AsyncTaskLoader instead? I know this doesn't answer your question but I gave up on AsyncTasks a while ago due to the many issues they pose when confronted with various aspects of the Activity life cycle. It may be worth a read:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Otherwise make sure to do various null checks in the onPostExecute() to make sure you aren't showing an AlertDialog without your Activity in the foreground.

Comment: Hi John, I've been reading up on AsyncTaskLoader. Thanks for the prompt! It seems quite like what we'll need to solve this. I think we'll still use AsyncTask in some areas of our app, because it seems that AsyncTaskLoader is suggested for when you want to make UI changes based on something that the task executed. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, if you post this solution as an answer, I'll mark it as correct if tested and proven to be a solution. :)

Comment: Excellent! I'll draft up an answer as soon as I get to a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` will still run after an `Activity` is navigated away from. This means that `onPostExecute()` may be called when an `Activity` is no longer visible and any UI changes that should be done in `onPostExecute()` will result in an `Exception`, most likely a `NullPointerException` or an `IllegalStateException`.

To remedy this, you will have to either manage the `AsyncTask` yourself by stopping it in your activity's `onPause()` and restarting it in your activity's `onResume()` or place the task in a retained non-UI `Fragment`. In my opinion, these solutions are a little hacky. I would highly recommend using an `AsyncTaskLoader` in place of an `AsyncTask` when the UI will be modified after the task executes. AsyncTaskLoaders use a `LoaderManager` which handles the Activity/Fragment lifecycle for you.

There are many resources that demonstrate the correct implementation of AsyncTaskLoaders, I have listed some of them below:

- [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)
- [Alex Lockwood's blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)
- [Wolfram Rittmeyer's blog post](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/)

I used the `AsyncTaskLoader` class in one of my open source applications, CrimeTalk Reader, to load web data using Jsoup and put the resuts in a `ListView`. The class that uses it can be found on [Github](https://github.com/JohnPersano/CrimeTalk-Reader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/org/crimetalk/fragments/ArticleListFragment.java).

In instances where you want to run a long-running task without UI interaction, you may want to check out the [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) class.